# Name of anime space dragon movie

Tags: story-identification, anime

I think it was in the late 70s/early 80s an anime movie appeared on HBO. During that time HBO mailed a monthly TV Guide of prominent movies being aired and I think it had a high profile spot.

I don't think the name of the movie is Space Dragon because I rented that already and it seemed different from what I remember.

I remember the main character tries to assemble the robot but is unable to and gets injured in the process.  It's kind of like the Voltron robot but with just one person controlling the robot.

Comment: Maybe one of the Getter Robo movies? I've not seen them, but some of the aspects sound like they *might* apply.

Comment: From what I can tell doing a search, Getter Robo seems to be series rather than a movie.

Comment: Getter Robo had some cross-over movies with Mazinger.

Comment: I think you might be looking for one of the shows in the [Force Five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_Five) series which got adapted into two hour long anthology movies.

Comment: Was it the Mighty Orbots? There was an episode featuring a space dragon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Svfdhzf8LrI

Comment: @Dre No, don't think so. I remember the cartoon being a movie and one of the characters died at the end.

Comment: @Krazer it is indeed the Gaiking Force Five series. If you would like to create an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it was part of the *[Force Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_Five)* American adaptation of five different anime television series.

The particular series *Force Five: Gaiking* is an adaptation of the original *[Divine Demon-Dragon Gaiking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaiking)*:

> The story chronicled the battle between the crew of the semi-transformable carrier Daikū Maryū (also called the Kargosaur in the US version, and also known as The Great Space Dragon) and the Super Robot Gaiking invented by Dr. Daimonji (Prof. Hightech in the English-language version of the show) against an invading race of aliens called the Dark Horror Army from the planet Zela whose home planet is facing destruction by a black hole as their population starts to mutate (the fact that their giant bearded ruler now wears his mouth on his forehead is considered only a minor mutation).
>
> Notable aspects of the series include the dinosaur-based designs of the Daikū Maryū and its support machines and the use of part of the carrier to form the main robot. The robot Gaiking was piloted by former baseball star named Sanshiro Tsuwabuki (Sanshiro's name was changed to Aries Astronopolis for the English version with the carrier being called the "Great Space Dragon", a literal translation of "Daikū Maryū". Likewise, for the Latin America version the main character was called Brando Drummond and the carrier "Gran Dragon del Espacio") who was drafted for the job because his latent psychic powers made him the only one capable of doing so, all other similarly empowered candidates having been assassinated by alien agents with he himself having been injured in an attack that ended his sports career. Gaiking is most easily distinguished from other mecha by its skull-shaped golden torso formed from the head of the Daikū Maryū and its golden horns.